# Why does int.Parse not work on an Enum value?

Tags: c#, .net

can you tell me how this first line converts to int and second doesn't work?

```
public enum SomeEnumerator { AndHisValue, second, third }

int a = (int)(SomeEnumerator.AndHisValue);

int a = int.Parse(SomeEnumerator.AndHisValue);
```

Type of `AndHisValue` is string.

[Image](https://prnt.sc/nu3puy)

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: And you can't cast a string to an int like that, so if the first line works, then I don't think `AndHisValue` is really a string.

Comment: It cannot convert from string, okay - maybe i should ask like this:

Comment: How is (int) able to give me the number of index?

Comment: I’m guessing you’re enumerating a string, in which case your casting a char (an integral type) to int, but parse requires a string.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nu3puy

Comment: Thank you all, but wheres this char type? Where did you take it from ?! :))

Comment: @gooscyora That's not an enumerator, that's an enum, they're different. Enums are really just `int` by default, so they can be cast to an `int`. `int.Parse` is for parsing a string representation of a number into an integer.

Comment: Thank YOU all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you show in your image, `SomeEnumerator` is not of type string, but instead an `enum`.

`string` constants are denoted by " around them. `enum` constants, such as `SomeEnumerator.AndHisValue` are their own kind of value, each usually having their own distinct value.

You are allowed to directly cast any `enum`-value to `int` or `string`, but as `int.Parse()` expects a `string` you cannot use your enumerator value here

(see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum as reference for enums)